# apply properties from xml file to form

Tags: c#, xml, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# loading a XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141268/c-sharp-loading-a-xml-file)

i got a problem with my program. I need to read some xml file in which i have Form properties that i need to apply to my program at running(loading) it. I got this code, but at run it gives me a error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object). I'm lost now and really don't know how else to apply those setting from xml to my program.

```
<Form>
   <Size>
     <Width>558</Width> 
     <Height>537</Height> 
   </Size>
   <Text>XML saving</Text> 
   <Name>Test_name</Name> 
</Form>
```

```
    public formaENA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\testXML.xml");

        var form = from size in newDoc.Descendants("Size")
                    select new
                    {
                        Width = Convert.ToInt32(size.Element("Width").Value),
                        Height = Convert.ToInt32(size.Element("Height").Value)           
                    };

        foreach(var size in form)
        {
            formaENA.ActiveForm.Width = size.Width;
            formaENA.ActiveForm.Height = size.Height;              
        }
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: formaENA.ActiveForm.Width = size.Width; here

Comment: It might be that `formaENA.ActiveForm` is null.

Comment: Everything form a visual standpoint looks fine except for `formaENA.ActiveForm.Width` where is that declared..? has it even beein Initialized ..? It would really help if you show all relevant parts of that code in your question.. if formaENA has not been `newed` then the error you are seeing is truly correct

Comment: fromaENA is my form...i have only this code...that's all

Comment: It's not duplicate i got now that problem with this exception now with xml parsing...

Comment: `ActiveForm` can be null if there is no active form. You must check it first.

Comment: Have you walked through the code in the debugger to check the values of form.ENA.ActiveForm.Width and size.Width?

Comment: Maybe you should put the code somewhere else, not `Form1_Load` which may have been the cause there is no active form yet.

Comment: Also, it you are creating a MDI app, you should use `ActiveMdiChild` instead and it it's a SDI you may possibly want to do `this.Width` instead

Comment: @František i have code now in button click method and it apply me those values and form resizes but i still get same exception...any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Drago Flirt: does it help when you use `this.Width` instead of `formaENA.ActiveForm.Width`? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and what's you configuration.

Comment: @František Žiačik i'm trying to resize my form on button click or on form load, i get value from xml file. With this.Width it's the same.

Comment: With this.Width i get exception here(on end of select):
Convert.ToInt32(size.Element("Height").Value)
                       };//here is exception

Comment: I Got it, problem was that i have more as one <Size> in my xml file.
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have not initialized formaENA. If it dosn't have a static property named ActiveForm you should get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are getting this error because you haven't initialized formaENA. 
Try creating that form before you assing any property to it.

```
    formaENA frm = new formaENA();
    foreach(var size in form)
    {
        frm.Width = size.Width;
        frm.Height = size.Height;              
    }
    frm.Show();
```